# Always show extended items for frontend user

Tags: typo3, extbase

I created an extension in TYPO3 8.7 and extended fe_users with new field `"acceptedagb"`. It is only shown if I select `"Tx_Feuserextend_User"` in data type. So is it possible to show the new fields always, also if nothing is selected? On other extensions like "news" it is possible ...

thanks for help!
martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this for me to set default value in page TSConfig:

```
TCAdefaults.fe_users.tx_extbase_type = Tx_Feuserextend_User
```

Answer (score 0):

The extension does a bit more magic as it generates proxy classes.

What you can do is this in your TypoScript

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
    YourVendor\YourNamespace\Domain\Model\User {
        mapping {
            tableName = fe_users
        }
    }
 }
```

The model would look like this

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourNamespace\Domain\Model;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser;


class User extends FrontendUser
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $addresses;

    ... getter / setters

 }
```

Now you can use your model everywhere in your extension.

---

**Important to know:** Everywhere, where the original model `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser` is used, the new property is still not available and there is no real way to add it there.

Comment: thanks! I added it to template -> setup and changed also ext_typoscript_setup.txt - but new field are only shown if I select data type ...?

Comment: yes, thanks. in frontend i can get datas from new fields. but i want to see new fields in backend. i only can see them if i select "Tx_Feuserextend_User" in data type ...